# Why don't we take into account the auto-protonation of water when measuring its concentration?

Tags: equilibrium, aqueous-solution, concentration

When we calculate the concentration of water at  $ 25~^\circ\rm C $,
why don't we assume *dissociation of water* at this temperature?

$$\ce{H2O <=> H+ + OH-}$$

Comment: I didn't get it. What should we assume, and how?

Comment: Because the number of moles of dissociated water is so slight compared to the number of moles of undissociated water, it makes no practical difference to our calculations to ignore the dissociated fraction.

Comment: Compare the free energy to perform the dissociation with the thermal energy $kT$.

Comment: If you take a look at the equilibrium constant for your reaction, you'll see why. @Ivan please don't forget about bad titles, for the sake of Mart-the-mod's heart. :)

Answer (score 1):

The equilibrium constant of the reaction is 
 $$\ce{H2O <=> H+ + OH-}$$
is 10^-14 and hence only 1 atom of water in 10^7 dissociates which really is negligible.